# как красиво перевести метафору to chisel, to carve out the gem from the rock?

Tags: перевод

Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести метафору в предложении. So we worked collectively to chisel, to carve out the gem from the rock.

Comment: Прежде чем просить о помощи с переводом - покажите что вы пробовали и в чем загвоздка. Иначе вопрос может быть закрыт.

Comment: @Artemix, проблема в том, что дословный перевод "высечь драгоценный камень из камня" меня не устраивает) Есть еще вариант "высечь бриллиант из алмаза". Но я надеюсь, что кто-то подскажет более литературный перевод

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. огранить этот алмаз
2. отсечь все лишнее от глыбы мрамора

Возможно, второй вариант для более подготовленного читателя. Разные варианты этой фразы приписываются Родену и Микеланджело.

Comment: спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1):

> Мы приложили немало усилий,чтобы превратить неграненый алмаз в бриллиант чистой воды.

Не зная контекста,конечно...

Comment: Somewhat rather cheesy

Answer (score -2):

вот так: "сделать из говна конфетку"